# Response after JSON parsing in POST method giving code status 400 in iOS

Tags: ios, json, http-post, nsjsonserialization, rest-client

I am calling a web-service using `POST method` in Objective C (iOS). I am encoding the parameters in `NSUTF8StringEncoding` and then embedding it to the url. And I am getting response in `JSON format`.

But the response I am getting is :
`<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x8df87e0> { URL: http://local.server/Servi1.svc/Register } { status code: 400, headers { "Content-Length" = 1675; etc etc..... Date, Server n all}}`

But the same URL in POST method when I am requesting in `Firefox REST Client`, I am getting the correct response.

Can anyone help me out?

```
    {
     NSString * strBodyOnlineStart = [NSString
stringWithFormat:@"mobile_key=%@&key=%@",key,strId];
    urlOnlineStart = [NSURL
URLWithString:@"http://local.server/Servi1.svc/Register"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestOnlineStart = [NSMutableURLRequest
requestWithURL:urlOnlineStart];
    [requestOnlineStart setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSData *requestBodyOnlineStart = [strBodyOnlineStart
dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [requestOnlineStart setHTTPBody:requestBodyOnlineStart];
    NSURLResponse *responseOnlineStart = NULL;
    NSError *requestErrorOnlineStart = NULL;
    NSData *responseDataOnlineStart = [NSURLConnection
sendSynchronousRequest:requestOnlineStart returningResponse:&responseOnlineStart
error:&requestErrorOnlineStart];

    NSDictionary *jsonDictOnlineStart = [NSJSONSerialization
JSONObjectWithData:responseDataOnlineStart options:kNilOptions error:nil];

  arrayOfQuestions = [ jsonDictOnlineStart objectForKey:@"data"];
}
```

Comment: Add some code of your json parsing .

Comment: Show code how you call service.

Comment: Is this because of the encoding type I am using which the server not able to understand?

Comment: try my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721885/url-decoding-of-json-in-ios/12722588#12722588)

Comment: This is the response I am getting after trying @Chinntu's code <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    
    <head>
    
    <title>Request Error</title>
    
    <style>BODY { color: #000000; ......... #e5e5cc;}</style>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    <div id="content">
    
    <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
    
    <p>The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.</p>
        
        </div>
        
        </body>
        
        </html>